# How to run chromium browser as a normal user?

Tags: linux, browser, chromium

When I try to start chromium I get this:

> Please start Chromium as **a normal user**. If you have previously run Chromium as a root, you will need to change the ownership of your profile directory.

I searched for it, but found articles only like run chromium *as a root*. I use linux (Ubuntu) not a long time, that I need a help.

*Addition* If I add new normal user, how can I run chromium from root like them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run Chromium with an argument from the command line like this

> chromium --user-data-dir=/foo/bar

This will enable you to run it as root. This is not advised though for security reasons.

If by *running as a normal user* you mean execute the command as someone else, you can just do

> su - username -c "chromium --user-data-dir=/foo/bar"

if you need to use the user's settings, then the path(user-data-dir) should point to them.

Comment: Sorry, but I beginner in Linux, I didn't understand something which you wrote. I tried to run in terminal "chromium --user-data-dir=/foo/bar", but I got "command no found".

Comment: @clank if you just try to execute "chromium" alone, does it say the same thing? btw try entering an existing folder.. for example if you have a user named"steve" then try /home/steve

Comment: I reboot system and try again, it has been worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If username and password is already set in your Linux System then, answer by @Dropout is perfect.
If there is no password set and you want to *run as a normal user*, you can just do

```
su -c "chromium --user-data-dir=/foo/bar"
```

This will allow you to open Chromium when you don't have a password defined in your Linux System